# Conditional probability question about a volleyball team

Tags: probability

> Amir and Babak are members of the school volleyball team of ten. No two players are equal in this team. If we know Amir is taller than Babak, How likely is Amir to be ninth in height?

Is this solution true?
$$P(C|B)=[P(C)\cdot P(B|C)]/P(B)
=
[(1/10)\cdot (1/9)]/(1/2)=1/45$$
Could someone tell me if I got this right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. This is a different approach without conditional probability. Since Amir is taller than Babak in a team of $10$ then there are $\binom{10}{2}=45$ ways to arrange them along the decreasing line. If Amir is the ninth in height then Babak is the tenth one and therefore the probability is
$\frac{1}{45}.$